# Django function based view get_form_kwargs

Tags: django, view

I have the following problem.

Normally in Django Class based views the `get_form_kwargs` method is used to supply the kwargs to the forms `__init__()`. For example:

```
class ComponentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    diameter = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Diameter.objects.all(), label='Diameter') # required=True, 

    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = [
            'component_type',
            'diameter',
            'length'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        circuit = kwargs.pop('circuit')
        project = kwargs.pop('project')
        super(ComponentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['diameter'].queryset = Diameter.objects.filter(project=project, material = circuit.material_type)
```

In the example code above, the "circuit" and "project" are supplied by the get_form_kwargs method in the corresponding view.

The question is now how to pass these kwargs to the ComponentForm `__init__()` using a function based view?

Answer (score 3):

Two ways.

Specify the directly in the constructor call.

```
form = ComponentForm(keyword_arg1=value1, keyword_args2=value2)
```

Alternatively build up a dictionary and pass it in with **kwargs syntax - I find this useful when dynamically adding attributes, and also when using inheritance (like the call to super().**init**() in your example).

```
kwargs = {keyword_arg1: value1}
kwargs.update({keyword_arg2:value2}) # usually with conditionals to specify what gets added
form = ComponentForm(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just pass them.

```
form = ComponentForm(circuit=whatever, project=whatever)
```